# Sscanf and detect input conversion errors [C]

Tags: c, scanf

I want to convert a program argument into double. Simple: I want to pass to my program a double value as an argument. But to make it right I wanted to detect conversion errors. I found out that `atof` isnt a good choice, so I switched to `sscanf`. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    argc --;
    argv++;

    double s;
    int handle =-1;

    handle = sscanf(*argv, "%lf", &s);
            if(handle == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input double!\n");

            }else{ printf("%f\n", s);}

    return 0;
}
```

But on a wrong input, ie.: `./code blabla` it prints out 0.0000000000 Whats wrong?

Comment: Replace `if(handle == -1)` by `if(handle <1)`

Comment: Don't use scanf family.

Comment: @Armin: yup, I know. When I print out my passed double: `printf("%s\n", *argv);` it printed out a double I gave as input.

Comment: @nouney: is there any other alternative for C?

Comment: @nouney: What's your rationale for not using the `scanf` family, except that in this simple case `strtod` would probably be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) instead of the `scanf` family. It returns `0.0` if no number could be parsed (unfortunately also when the number is actually `0.0`). You can use the `endptr` argument to check where the function stopped parsing the number, so that can be used to check if the string contains a valid number. It sets `errno` when the value can't be represented.

Answer (score 2):

From the [*Linux Programmer's Manual* on `scanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE):

> ### Return Value
>
> These functions return **the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero** in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value `EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see `error(3)`) is set, and `errno` is set indicate the error.

Ergo, you should check for `handle < 1`.

You can also try `strtod(3)`.